# Getting details from enumerated target domain

Tags: windows, security

so I am doing a cyber sec lab and one of the questions is to find the max password policy on the target domain

with enum4linux I have been able to get this

The questions has you chose between 32 days, 64 and 128

```
+] Password Info for Domain: ELS-WINXP

[+] Minimum password length: 4
[+] Password history length: None
[+] Maximum password age: 32 days 2 minutes
[+] Password Complexity Flags: 000000

[+] Domain Refuse Password Change: 0
[+] Domain Password Store Cleartext: 0
```

Would this suggest that it is 32 hours ? or something more than 32 hours because it says 32hrs 2 mins...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. Might be suitable for other SE sites like Security SE, but please read about what is on-topic there before posting.